# How to loop through an array of JSON objects using the http client and Observables in Angular

Tags: json, angular, rxjs, observable, angular-httpclient

I have the following url https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_day.geojson and i want to make a http request from a service in Angular.

The data is an Object which has an array of Features. 
In Features, there are 4 Objects- type, properties, geometry & id.
I would like to store the **properties** and **geometry** objects in their own array inside my application.

How can I do this?

The code i have in my **service.ts** is :

```
 public getEarthquakeData(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<any[]>(this.url);
  }
```

I know how to call this service from my component but I am not sure how to loop through / access the data I want to save.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where do you want to store the data? In the service?

Comment: what is the shape of your expected output ?

Comment: @KurtHamilton I want to store the data in the component. So i know i need to subscribe in the component.

Comment: @Reza im not too sure. I think that's why i'm a little confused. maybe it would be best to store each feature in an array? but if i did that, how could I access feature.properties for example

Comment: @HiddenSquid so you want to have `geometries: Array<Geometries>` and `properties: Array<Properties>` in your component./service?

Comment: @Reza yes, because then I would like to be able to loop through them and display them in a chart / table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response of the url you posted looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "",
  "metadata": [],
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {},
      "id": ""
    }
  ],
  "bbox": []
}
```

You are interested in extracting an array of `properties` and an array of `geometry`. It makes sense to do this in your service if you want to share this functionality.

To do that, you will need to transform the response in an RxJS `map` operator in the pipe.

```js
public getEarthquakeData(): Observable<{ properties: [], geometries: []}> {
  return this.httpClient.get<any>(this.url).pipe(
    // this will run when the response comes back
    map((response: any) => {
      return {
        properties: response.features.map(x => x.properties),
        geometries: response.features.map(x => x.geometry)
      };
    })
  );
}
```

Then when you subscribe to this function in your component, you will receive an object that looks like:

```
{
  "properties": [],
  "geometries": []
}
```

component.ts

```js
properties: [];
geometries: [];

ngOnInit() {
  this.earthquakeService.getEarthquakeData().subscribe(data => {    
   this.properties = data.properties;
   this.geometries = data.geometries;
 });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I was looking for and works as intended.

Could you possibly help with another question I have? [QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60542279/how-to-use-behavioursubjects-to-share-data-from-api-call-between-components-in-a)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
.......
properties: Array<any>;
geometries: Array<any>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.earthquakeService.getEarthquakeData().pipe(
    // pluck the features array from the object
    map(data => data.features),
  ).subscribe(features => {
   // this will give you the array of objects you would like
   this.properties = features.map(feature => feature.properties);
   this.geometries = features.map(feature => feature.geometry);
 });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick stackblitz I put together on how I would approach this.  If you dont want to use a service for storing your data just move the pipe on the http call to your component before the subscribe and change tap to map.

That said I would highly recommend you store the results in the service and use a route resolver to trigger the data get and then you can use the data subscription in your actual component.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ccqrju

Something else the service route here preserves the original data should you want to store and use it in other ways as well.