# How to use BehaviourSubjects to share data from API call between components in Angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-httpclient, behaviorsubject

I am currently building an Angular application where I make a request to an api, and I map the repsonse to two different arrays. I can use this data in my `app.components.ts` but I will make new components for what I need. How can I share the data between components to ensure that the components always have the latest data because I will also need to periodically call the API.

I've seen some answers on SO and some youtube videos but I'm just not fully understanding it.

The code of my service is

```
 url = 'https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_day.geojson'; 
  private _earthquakePropertiesSource = new BehaviorSubject<Array<any>>([]);
  private _earthquakeGeometrySource = new BehaviorSubject<Array<any>>([]);


  constructor(private readonly httpClient: HttpClient) {

  }


  public getEarthquakeData(): Observable<{ properties: [], geometries: []}> {
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(this.url).pipe(
      // this will run when the response comes back
      map((response: any) => {
        return {
          properties: response.features.map(x => x.properties),
          geometries: response.features.map(x => x.geometry)
        };
      })
    );
  }
```

It is being used in my `app.component.ts` as follows:

```
 properties: Array<any>;
 geometries: Array<any>;

constructor(private readonly earthquakeService: EarthquakeService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.earthquakeService.getEarthquakeData().subscribe(data => {
      this.properties = data.properties;
      this.geometries = data.geometries;
      this.generateMapData();
    });
  }

  generateMapData() {
    for (const g of this.geometries) {
      const tempData: any = {
        latitude: g.coordinates[0],
        longitude: g.coordinates[1],
        draggable: false,
      };
      this.mapData.push(tempData);
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an answer describing how it can be done using pure RxJS. Another alternative is to use NgRx.

Firstly, you have set up two subjects. The intention being that all components will subscribe to them and receive the latest data when it is refreshed?

You should use `ReplaySubject` instead of `BehaviorSubject` though, since you don't have any initial state. And since the data comes back as one thing, I would use one subject.

Firstly, I am going to declare an interface to make it easier to talk about the data types.

earthquake-data.ts

```js
export interface EarthquakeData {
  // TODO: create types for these
  geometries: any[]; 
  properties: any[];
}
```

In your service, you can separate the retrieval and the notifications by exposing the data via your own methods.

earthquake.service.ts

```js
  url = 'https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_day.geojson'; 

  private _earthquakeData$ = new ReplaySubject<EarthquakeData>(1);

  constructor(private readonly httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getEarthquakeData(): Observable<EarthquakeData> {
    // return the subject here
    // subscribers will will notified when the data is refreshed
    return this._earthquakeData$.asObservable(); 
  }

  refreshEarthquakeData(): Observable<void> {
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(this.url).pipe(
      tap(response => {
        // notify all subscribers of new data
        this._earthquakeData$.next({
          geometries: response.features.map(x => x.geometry),
          properties: response.features.map(x => x.properties)
        });
      })
    );
  }
```

So now, all components that want to receive data will subscribe to one method:

```js
private destroyed$ = new Subject();

ngOnInit()
  this.earthquakeService.getEarthquakeData().pipe(
    // it is now important to unsubscribe from the subject
    takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
  ).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data); // the latest data
  });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.destroyed$.next();
  this.destroyed$.complete();
}
```

And you can refresh the data wherever you want to:

```js
refreshData() {
  this.refreshing = true;
  this.earthquakeService.refreshEarthquakeData().subscribe(() => {
    this.refreshing = false;
  });
}
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uv7j33

Comment: Hi Kurt. Thank you for your detailed response. 
I tried to implement the solution you provided but I am getting a few errors.

```
cannot find name geometries
cannot find name properties
cannot find name response
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a couple of typos. I've corrected them and added a demo link

Comment: No problem, Thanks a lot! So now i can call the getEarthquakeData() and refreshEarthquakeData() the same in all my components?

Comment: Yep - any component can subscribe and refresh. Refresh doesn't need to be unsubscribed, because http calls are self-completing. Your get will need to be unsubscribed, because they subscribe to a subject you have created yourself.

Comment: Do I need to unsubscribe in the ngOnDestroy() in the components ? 
Also, How would I be able to make the api call every x minutes?

Comment: My example is effectively unsubscribing in `ngOnDestroy`. That's what `takeUntil` is doing - it will unsubscribe when `destroyed$` emits a value.

Comment: Use `timer` from `'rxjs'` to perform polling. `timer(0, x).pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$), switchMap(() => this.earthquakeService.refreshData()))`

Comment: Note that you will also have to unsubscribe from timer

Comment: so i call ```timer(0, 100).pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$), switchMap(() => 
  
    this.earthquakeService.refreshEarthquakeData()))``` in the ngOnInit()  alongside the original two subscriptions?

Comment: I've updated my stackblitz. You would only need to kick off the refresh in one place per active component.

Answer (score 0):

### Edit 1

Service:

```
 url = 'https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_day.geojson'; 
  properties = new BehaviorSubject<Array<any>>([]);
  geometries = new BehaviorSubject<Array<any>>([]);


  constructor(private readonly httpClient: HttpClient) {
    loadEarthquakeData().
  }


  public loadEarthquakeData(): Observable<{ properties: [], geometries: []}> {
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(this.url).pipe(
      tap((response: any) => {
        this.properties.next(response.features.map(x => x.properties);
        this.geometries.next(response.features.map(x => x.geometry));
      })
    ).toPromise();
  }
```

Component:

```
  private _subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private readonly earthquakeService: EarthquakeService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.generateMapData();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this._subscription) {
      this._subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

  generateMapData() {
    this._subscription = this.earthquakeService.geometries.subscribe(geometries => {
      for (const g of this.earthquakeService.geometries.getValue()) {
        const tempData: any = {
          latitude: g.coordinates[0],
          longitude: g.coordinates[1],
          draggable: false,
        };
        this.mapData.push(tempData);
      }
    });
  }
```

#### Original

For that, you need [Angular Services](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4)

They are singletons that can act like a shared state. What you want to do is to store your data inside the service, and then call the service from both of your components and listen to the service's BehaviorSubject.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am currently using services. The first code snippet is of my service but I am not sure how to implement the BehaviourSubject functionality so that I can keep track of the state

Answer (score 0):

To share information between components you can use a behaviorSubject in a service that will be used in your different components.

The BehaviorSubject has the characteristic that it stores the “current” value, the last value,  that needs to be shared with other components.

Its particularity is:

- **need an initial value**

  const subject = new MyBehaviorSubject('initialValue');
- **return the last value of the subject**
- **You can retrieve the last value with getValue() method** ( non observable)

  subject.getValue()
- **you can subscribe to it**:

  subject.subscribe(console.log);
- **update the value with next()**

  subject.next('New value');

I give you an example: 
in my service:

```
 private isOpen = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

   public getNavBarOpen(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.isOpen.asObservable();
  }

    setNavBarOpen(status: boolean): void {
     this.isOpen.next(status);
  }
```

in my component:

if I want to update the value :

```
this.myService.setNavBarOpen(true);
```

If i want to get the value :

```
this.myService.getNavBarOpen().subscribe()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include a property on the service that will hold this data, and subscribe to it instead. I'm assuming you'll have a timed interval checking for new responses - which can then just update the value of the property in the service.

```
export interface earthQuakeResponse {
    properties: Array<any>
    geometries: Array<any>
}

export class EarthQuakeService {
    private _earthQuakeResponse = new BehaviorSubject<earthQuakeResponse>([]);
    readonly earthQuakeResponse = this._earthQuakeResponse.asObservable();

    public getEarthquakeData(): Observable<earthQuakeResponse> {
            return this.earthQuakeResponse;
    }

    //call this method when you want to update your data
    private updateData() {
            this.httpClient.get<any>(this.url).subscribe(
                    response => {
                        this._earthQuakeResponse.next({
                            properties: response.features.map(x => x.properties),
                            geometries: response.features.map(x => x.geometry)
                        });
                    });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to go about this, would be to use `BehaviorSubject`. The documentation on this is comprehensive, I'm sure you can find it.

To handle complex state in large applications, people use Redux. For Angular, there is NgRx.

If updating state requires you to call an API as a side effect, use `ngrx/effects`

https://ngrx.io/guide/effects

Answer (score 0):

The service method doesn't need return an Observable:

```
public getEarthquakeData(): Observable<{ properties: [], geometries: []}> {
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(this.url).pipe(
     // this will run when the response comes back
    tap((response: any) => {
      _earthquakePropertiesSource.next(response.features.map(x => x.properties));
      _earthquakeGeometrySource.next(response.features.map(x => x.geometry));
    })
});
```

And the component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    combineLatest(
        this.earthquakeService._earthquakePropertiesSource,
        this.earthquakeService._earthquakeGeometrySource
    ).subscribe(data => {
      this.properties = data[0];
      this.geometries = data[1];
      this.generateMapData();
});
}
```